# Gradle execution failed for task

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Once a while while building my project i keep getting:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:packageProductionDebug'.
> value (115422) > 0x0000ffff
```

This happens for 30%-50% attempts to run my project regardless of device.

I've tried to clean my project but still no luck.

The `value (115422)`seems to be changing but the hex value remains the same.

**EDIT**

My gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1"
    buildConfigField 'String', 'BUILD_DIR', "\"${project.buildDir}\""
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

/* set file name depending on build variant*/
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def filename = applicationId
        if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
            filename += '-debug';
        } else {
            filename += '-vc-' + variant.versionCode
        }
        filename += '.apk'
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                filename
        )
    }
}

productFlavors{
    staging{
        applicationId = 'com.myapp.beta'
        manifestPlaceholders = [activityLabel:"myapp.STAGING"]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    production {
        applicationId = 'com.myapp'
        manifestPlaceholders = [activityLabel:"myapp"]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    instrTest {
        applicationId = 'com.myapp'
        manifestPlaceholders = [activityLabel:"myapp"]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
    }

}
sourceSets {
    main{
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']

        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }
    productionDebug{
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/test/assets']
    }
    stagingDebug{
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/test/assets']
    }
    staging {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/staging/java']
    }
    production{
        java.srcDirs = ['src/production/java']
    }
    instrTest{
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/test/assets']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/instrTest/java']
        manifest.srcFile 'src/instrTest/AndroidManifest.xml'
        res.srcDirs = ['src/instrTest/','src/instrTest/res']
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'

compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0-rc1'

compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:6.3.+'

compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.10'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'biz.source_code:base64coder:2010-09-21'
compile 'org.iban4j:iban4j:3.0.4'
compile 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.4.0@aar'
compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.9@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.tsums.androidcookiejar:androidcookiejar:1.0@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest:1.0.16'
testCompile ('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"

compile project(':cropimage')
compile project(':viewpagerindicator')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

I've also tried to run the tasks from terminal with `--stack` option and got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value (172858) > 0x0000ffff
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:148)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZipField.write(ZipField.java:228)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.StoredEntry.toHeaderData(StoredEntry.java:651)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZFile.writeEntry(ZFile.java:944)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:858)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:900)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:128)
        at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:214)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:343)
        at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:214)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:448)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doIncrementalTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:580)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.doIncrementalTaskAction(PackageApplication.java:82)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:108)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: post the `build.gradle` file here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain [but I'm pretty sure it's a bug in Android Studio 2.2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211156), and do not have enough reputation to make a comment. Killing Java(.exe) fixes it.